# MySQL query optimization 5

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am working on an accounting software with JAVA + MySQL (maria db). I calculate the amount of the query with the following query, and the query takes 16 seconds when I run the query. is query duration normal? Do I make a mistake in the question?

```
SELECT products_id as ID,prod_name as 'Product Name',
       IFNULL((SELECT sum(piece)
               FROM `ktgcari_000_fatura_xref` 
               WHERE product_id = ktgcari_000_stok.products_id AND
                     (type = 1 or type = 4)
              ), 0) -
       IFNULL((SELECT sum(piece)
               FROM `ktgcari_000_fatura_xref` 
               WHERE product_id = ktgcari_000_stok.products_id AND 
                     (type = 2 or type = 5)
              ), 0) +
       IFNULL((SELECT sum(piece)
               FROM ktgcari_000_ssayim 
               WHERE urun_id = ktgcari_000_stok.products_id
               ), 0) as stock
FROM ktgcari_000_stok
LIMIT 0,1000
```

Stock=(sum of incoming invoice + sum of incoming dispatch) - (sum of outgoing invoice + total of outgoing dispatch) + (total of counting receipt)

Database Information:
number of stock cards: 39000
Number of invoices: 545
Invoice content table count: 1800
Number of counting fingers: 942
database size: 5 MB

[image: explain output]

Comment: Have you created index for required field?

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT s.products_id as ID, s.prod_name as `Product Name`,
       (COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x.type IN (1, 4) THEN piece
                                  WHEN x.type IN (2, 5) THEN - piece
                             END)
                FROM `ktgcari_000_fatura_xref` x
                WHERE x.product_id = s.products_id AND
                      x.type IN (1, 2, 4, 5)
                  ), 0) +
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(ss.piece)
                  FROM ktgcari_000_ssayim ss
                  WHERE ss.urun_id = s.products_id
                 )), 0
       ) as stock
FROM ktgcari_000_stok s
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Then for performance, you want indexes on `ktgcari_000_fatura_xref(product_id, type, piece)` and `ktgcari_000_ssayim(urun_id, piece)`.

I also note that you are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  You do realize that SQL result sets are *unordered*, unless they have an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the sql query as follows. the query time was 8 sec. how can i reduce the duration.

> SELECT products_id as ID,prod_name,(SELECT IF(type=1 or
>   type=4,sum(urun_adet),0)-IF(type=2 or type=5,sum(urun_adet),0) FROM
>   `ktgcari_000_fatura_xref` where
>   product_id=ktgcari_000_stok.products_id)+IFNULL((SELECT sum(miktar)
>   FROM ktgcari_000_ssayim where urun_id=ktgcari_000_stok.products_id),0)
>   as 'stock' FROM ktgcari_000_stok LIMIT 0,1000

[image: description]